# Raising i to a large power on a Ti-83

Tags: complex-numbers, calculator

When I input this on my graphing calculator I get the correct answer:

```
i^4
1
```

However when I do this with larger numbers I get a weird answer

```
i^64
1-3.6E^-12i
```

Despite the fact that the answer to i^64 is also 1.  Why does the calculator start to have problems with large powers of i?

Comment: Perhaps because $64\times\frac{\pi}2$ is irrational and it is facing rounding issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

floating point errors... its simply because the calculator is using a general algorithm to solve this, and the calculator has to round a little to store the bits in memory, so the result is a little off. Of course, the calculator is only $0.0000000000036$ off; not bad. When you encounter this it is pretty safe to drop the extra part.

Comment: This is a nice example of a case where using your head beats relying on a calculator.